# Numpy calculate mean for sub range both rows and columns in 2D array

Tags: numpy

Hei I am trying to calculate the average for both row and column

Ex I have the array

```
a = np.array([
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
[2,3,6,1,7,4,3,6],
[6,3,5,8,9,2,6,8],
[6,2,5,8,9,3,2,7],
[5,7,3,4,7,8,5,3],
[7,3,4,5,7,4,5,6],
[5,3,7,6,7,8,4,2],
[5,4,7,7,2,1,6,4]])
```

I want to calculate the average of [1,2] from the 1st row and [2,3] from the 2nd row. The average is 2.0
Then I wan to calculate the average of [3,4] from 1st row and [6,1] from the 2nd row. And so on

The result is sat to a new array that is half the size.

I have the following code that does this,

The full code is

```
import numpy as np
import sys
a = np.array([
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
[2,3,6,1,7,4,3,6],
[6,3,5,8,9,2,6,8],
[6,2,5,8,9,3,2,7],
[5,7,3,4,7,8,5,3],
[7,3,4,5,7,4,5,6],
[5,3,7,6,7,8,4,2],
[5,4,7,7,2,1,6,4]])

ni = nj = 2
dim_i = a.shape[0]
dim_j = a.shape[1]
b = np.empty((int(a.shape[0]/ni), int(a.shape[1]/nj)))

for ii, i in enumerate(range(0, dim_i, ni)):
    for jj, j in enumerate(range(0, dim_j, nj)):
        flat = np.array([a[i][j:j+ni], a[i+1][j:j+ni]]).flatten()
        b[ii,jj] = np.mean(flat)

print(b)

[[2.   3.5  5.5  6.  ]
 [4.25 6.5  5.75 5.75]
 [5.5  4.   6.5  4.75]
 [4.25 6.75 4.5  4.  ]]
```

I am looking for faster and elegant way of doing this. As the real data has the size of few hundreds or more in each dimension.

Is that possible?

Mvh,
Birgir.

Comment: How can I make the calculation of the strides and shape more generic example if ni=4 and nj=2 or the other way ni=2 and nj=4. Also is it possible do use numpy.lib.stride_tricks if my array is 3D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of `numpy` *stride_tricks* module to reshape your array into a block shape.
one-liner solution:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
as_strided(a, shape=(4, 4, 2, 2), strides=(128, 16, 64, 8)).mean(axis=(2,3))
```

output:

```
array([[2.  , 3.5 , 5.5 , 6.  ],
       [4.25, 6.5 , 5.75, 5.75],
       [5.5 , 4.  , 6.5 , 4.75],
       [4.25, 6.75, 4.5 , 4.  ]])
```

Note that I define explicitly the *shape* and the *strides* but they can easily be inferred (for the generic case of 2*2 average pooling)

```
strides = tuple(map(lambda x: x*2, a.strides)) + a.strides
shape = tuple(map(lambda x: int(x / 2), a.shape)) + (2, 2)
```

The performance of this trick 10 time faster compared to *naive* loop

```
%%timeit
as_strided(a, shape=(4, 4, 2, 2), strides=(128, 16, 64, 8)).mean(axis=(2,3))
11.5 µs ± 44.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%%timeit
ni = nj = 2
dim_i = a.shape[0]
dim_j = a.shape[1]
b = np.empty((int(a.shape[0]/ni), int(a.shape[1]/nj)))

for ii, i in enumerate(range(0, dim_i, ni)):
    for jj, j in enumerate(range(0, dim_j, nj)):
        flat = np.array([a[i][j:j+ni], a[i+1][j:j+ni]]).flatten()
        b[ii,jj] = np.mean(flat)
128 µs ± 1.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

The gain is more significant for larger arrays(X200 for 1000*1000 array)